# unity 3d OnGUI Loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a small problem i am making calculator and i want to decrease my code lenght by writting for loop, for the number part, i solved problem for infinity loop on ("OnGUI") part, but now it dosen't show my any numbers, can someone explain to me why is that?
Thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Calculator : MonoBehaviour {
    int temp,rectX,t,count;
    bool endOfCalc;
    string val;

    private void Start()
    {
        endOfCalc = false;
        val = "";
        temp = 0;
        t = 9;
        count = 0;

        /*for(int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
        {
            rectX += 20;
            Debug.Log (rectX);
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect(10,160+rectX,30,20), x.ToString ()))
            {
                Calculation(x.ToString ());
            }
        }*/

    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        val = GUI.TextField (new Rect(10,100,200,20), val);

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect(40,120,30,20), "+"))
        {
            temp += int.Parse (val);
            val = "";
        }

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect(10,120,30,20),"="))
        {
            temp += int.Parse (val);
            val = temp.ToString ();
            endOfCalc = true;
        }

        // The problem is here, i can't see any buttons.
        for(int x= 0; x<=t; t--)
        {
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect(10,140,30,20), count.ToString()))
            {
                Calculation(count.ToString ());
            }

            count++;
        }
    }

    void Calculation(string str)
    {
        if (!endOfCalc)
            val += str;
        else
            val = "";
            val += str;
            endOfCalc = false;
            temp = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int x= 0; x<=t; t--)
```

I think this must be:

```
for(int x= 0; x<=t; x++)
```

`OnGui`is called at least once per frame. In the current implementation t is decremented to -1 during the very first call and will remain -1 as I can't see any other place where you set it back to 9.

Another point is the `Rect`: All buttons show up at the same position. The `rectX` offset approach commented out in `Start` seems what you need. But `rectX` is actually rather a rectY due to the constructor of Rect.

I think you avoid `count` then because it seems to be uninitialised:

```
for(int x= 0; x<=t; x++) { 
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect(10,140,30,20), x.ToString())) {
        Calculation(x.ToString ());
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

I just tried out the following code:

```
void OnGUI () {
    int offset = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++) { 
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10 + offset, 140, 30, 20), x.ToString ())) {
            Debug.Log ("Pressed: " + x);
        }
        offset += 35;
    }       
}
```

And got:
[image: Buttons created by for loop]

And some log output like:

```
Pressed: 4
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
MenuController:OnGUI() (at Assets/Scripts/Menu/MenuController.cs:53)
```

Comment: The button yes i know i will fix it later now need to fix this part, but at first i used `for (int x = 0; x<=t; t++)` but the problem is the loop will go forever, becouse it is in OnGUI, if i put in in Start i will have problems it will say GUI.Button, dosen't exist etc.. becouse there isn't called OnGUI Class, so i fooled the system, and made t--, for that i fixed infinity loop, and made int count to count from 0 to 9 numbers. :) If you didin't understand what i want to say, i will rewrite it more carefully, sorry i got bad english.

Comment: Try yourself, make debug.log(x); it will go forever :)

Comment: `OnGui`is the right place. Just **x++** instead of **t--**. See my updated answer about `count`. I assume t is const = 9

Comment: I will try it one more time, but i think the loop will go forever. K give a sec.   Yep, the problem is the same.

Comment: `t` is always 9, if there is no other code manipulating it. So you can declare it as `const int t = 9 or replace it by a hard-coded `9`. So I'm pretty sure that a `for(int x= 0; x <= 9; x++) { ...` will run 10 times

Comment: in Coding logic i am 100% thinking that you are right, but in unity `void OnGUI(){}` every frame this function code is called two times, so every second it just few times runs code, so every time it ruins it the for loop starts again, becouse in for (x = 0) and it is < 9, so for loop starts again, when the code goes trough all lines from top to button, very fast way it goes again becouse it is created to run this class two times every frame, so it again goes trough code and again the results are x < 9 so the loop starts again, i think you don't use unity? sorry if i insulted you but you would

Comment: tried in unity this code and you would saw the results. :) If i am mistaking sorry, just can't understand if i am explaining really that bad things :D

Comment: I believe you that it doesn't work ;-) But there must be something else (s. updated answer with my test). Maybe you have some other place where t is set to whatever value. Maybe you forgot `++` instead of `--` in `x++`. Make it as simple as you can by just copying my code - this should work. Then start integrating your own logic step by step.

Comment: Yes it worked, can't really undertstand why it dosen't worked when i tried earlier, it was my mistake i think sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I know these situations, that's software development ;-)

Answer (score 0):

when i look into your code i would say you only see one button, and all others are under that, because you always place them on the exact same place:

```
if (GUI.Button (new Rect(10,140,30,20), count.ToString()))
{
    Calculation(count.ToString ());
}
```

you have to change the position every "round", something like this:

```
if (GUI.Button (new Rect(10,30 * t + 140,30,20), count.ToString()))
{
    Calculation(count.ToString ());
}
```

Comment: i know that, the problem is i don't see any buttons at all, becouse for loop in OnGUI will go infinity times, so i made it until it reaches zero to fix this part, but when i press run online mode, i don't see not even one button. Can someone explain why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Look this is a bit complicated matter, in OnGUI Class if whe write `for (int x = 0; x<= 9; x++)` we will be in trouble, becouse in OnGUI Every frame this class is called two times so every frame two times x will be == 0 and will loop from 0 to 9 thats a problem, becouse i need to loop only once, ofcouse i can use start function, but there i don't know how to call a `GUI.Button...` so that's another problem so i fooled the system and used from 9 to 0 count and fixed infinity loop, but the problem is not there when i fixed the infinity loop what i write in that loop like example: `GUI.button` it dosen't show up, i need explaination why is that happening, thanks for reading. :) Thanks for answers.